# Replacing a free Windows Store app with a paid version

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-store

I have a windows store app which I built about two years ago. I released it as a free app, but now I'm thinking about switching to a trial / paid model. After the trial expires, the app would return to the free functionality and the user could pay to upgrade

My question is, can I replace a free app with a paid one?

By replace I mean, change the existing app to require payment, and keep the reviews etc. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You will need to follow the normal update process. Your new update should have the paid/trial functionality and when you upload the new version you can set a price. You can find help here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/apps/hh694065.aspx. If you want existing users to buy the app then you can look at in app purchasing.